# Can "must have + past participle" ever express obligation (deontic modality)?

Tags: modal-verbs, semantics, linguistics, deontic-vs-epistemic, modality

Can a sentence using a *must have* + past participle construction ever express deontic modality?

These are all epistemic:

- *He must have showered.*
- *Someone must have eaten the apple.*
- *The laundry must have finished already.*

This one could be deontic if the deadline is still in the future, otherwise it is also epistemic:

- *You must have submitted your apples by the deadline.*

I can conceive of a rule described like this:

- *You must have created at least one connected pawn chain within the allotted time to win.*

Is this deontic? Or epistemic somehow like this:

- *The allotted time is over.*
- *You have won.*
- → *You must have created one connected pawn chain.*

In general, what can be said about deontic *must* + present perfect ?

Comment: Can you provide more context? Deontic (D for Duty): *You must have submitted your apples by the deadline in order to win.* Epistemic (E for Eduction): *You must have submitted your apples by the deadline, otherwise you could not have won.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat what kind of context?

Comment: It looks like a tense issue, since many examples might be more simply expressed as *must* + bare infinitive.

Comment: Here is an example quote from the [English court system - see 6.1(3)](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/protocol/pre-action-protocol-for-low-value-personal-injury-employers-liability-and-public-liability-claims#6.1) "Where the insurer’s identity is not known, the claimant **must make** a reasonable attempt to identify the insurer and, in an employers’ liability claim, the claimant **must have carried out** a database search through the Employers’ Liability Tracing Office."

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat What if we switch "must" to "would"? I.e. "You would have submitted your apples by the deadline in order to win." Will it work (with modal "would" in its volitional meaning or in its meaning of something being expected)?

Comment: @Eugene — If I understand what you’re asking, you would need to say: *You would have submitted your apples by the deadline in order to have won.* And that would be speculation, not expectation.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat Thank you. I take your sentense in as following: "You possibly submitted your apples by the deadline in order to have won? Am I right?

Comment: @Eugene — Not really. To paraphrase, it means: *I don’t **know** if you submitted your apples, but I must assume (speculate) that you submitted them, because you could not have won the apple contest if you didn’t submit them.*

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat May I ask you two more questions, if you please?              
 The first one: What can be the implications of these patterns: 1. "I have never thought that he would have become a thief”. 2. “I had never thought that he would have become a thief”. 3 “I never thought that he would have become a thief”.

Comment: The second one: What are the grammatical roles of "would have become" throughout this patterns? I.e. Is it the 3-rd Conditional ("A has never thought/never thought that B would have become a thief even if he had been forced to") or the modal "would"+Perf.Inf. in the sense of speculation about smth. sending the action to the sphere of the past (A had never thought/never thought that B would have become a thief" - A wasn't sure but he had to asume that B had really become a thief). Or is it the Future Perfect in the Past (A never thought/had never thought that B would have become a thief)?

Comment: @Eugene —You should post a question for this.